# How to indentify number of lines present on the webpage using java?

Tags: java, selenium, gis

I am doing testing for one GIS website using selenium java. I have red lines plotted on the map. How do I identify the number of such lines present using java?

[image]

Comment: do you have the plotting values (x,y) ?

Comment: Depends on what GIS API is driving the display.

Comment: show us some sourcecode of the website

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me if this does not solve your problem. I do not have much information on your problem. I'm assuming that this map is probably inside a frame and you could not locate elements normally as you would in the other parts of the page.

If the red lines you're looking for are inside a frame, try switching to it first.

`driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("iFrameElementIdentifier")));`

And then you can easily locate the red lines inside the frame by looking for its property.

Something like:

`driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@color='FF0000']")).size();`

And get the count from it.